# Can I ask help with naming classes?

Tags: discussion

There are situations where I have a lot of trouble finding a good and expressive name for one of my classes. English is not my first language, so my "inner thesaurus" is not very big.

Is it allowed to ask a question to only get help with naming a class? Obviously the question would include an example usage of the class and a description of what it does.

Comment: That is a very localized problem and is very opinion based, so it really isn't a good idea.

Answer (score -2):

You could try [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Naming questions are a bit more [on-topic 
at Programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology), so I would go there first.  If your code is working and you are specific about what you want to improve (best practices for naming), it's [kinda on topic on code review](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364/is-asking-for-a-name-for-one-function-on-topic).

Comment: On P.SE, we'd still probably close the question as primarily opinion though.